# How to match only month and year part from datetime column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two inputs, Month and year.

```
  selectedMonth = DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Value;//1
  SelectedYear = DDLYear.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();//2013
```

I want to show records preset or not of that particular month and year instead of only date. I want show registered employee

sql query

```
select e.EnquiryId, RegistrationNumber, Name
from Branch as b
    left join Enq as e on b.Enqui = e.Enqu
where Reg = @RegNo
  and Pay=Cheque
```

I need if selected month =1 ad year=2015. If this present in payment date and cheque. Something like:

```
where Registratio = @RegNo
  and Payment(month) = selectedMonth
  and payment(year) = selectedyear
  and chequere(month) = selected Month
  and chequere(year) = selected year
```

My columns chequere and payment date are in datetime format.

Comment: Hi there, have you tried using DATEPART?
Example: DATEPART(month, PaymentDate) = selectedMonth and DATEPART(year, PaymentDate) = selectedYear

Comment: Which table(s) do RegistrationNumber, PaymentDate  and ChequeReceivedDate belong to?

Comment: Registration number-Enquiries,
Paymentdate and chequerecieveddate -BranchPaymentsDetails

Comment: no ii have not tried @dev_JORD

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to do this would be to construct a date within your application code:

```
selectedMonth = DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Value;//1
SelectedYear = DDLYear.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();//2013  

var date = new DateTime(int.Parse(SelectedYear), int.Parse(selectedMonth), 1);
```

Then pass this date as a parameter to your query:

```
where RegistrationNumber = @RegNo
  and PaymentDate >= @Date
  and paymentdate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)
  and chequereceiveddate >= @Date
  and chequerecieveddate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date);
```

This makes your query [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), and means you don't need to perform `DATEPART()` functions on your columns.

Comment: Interesting approach. I've never seen a date query done this way before, I've learn't something today. +1.

Comment: @dev_JORD You may not have learnt something new. I have left parts in the query that made it utter nonsense and it wouldn't have compiled. I have corrected the query now.

Answer (score 0):

GarethD offers the best solution, but another way of doing it is by using DATEPART.

Example:

```
where RegistrationNumber = @RegNo
and DATEPART(month, PaymentDate) = selectedMonth
and DATEPART(year, PaymentDate) = selectedYear
and DATEPART(month, chequerecieveddate) = selectedMonth
and DATEPART(year, chequerecieveddate) = selectedYear
```

This is just to give an example of DATEPART() which would be more useful if you wanted to find an average of payments in certain months for example.